# How do we persist previous request values in second request python

Tags: python, session, flask

I set username and password in the first request. However, I need to persist the username and password in the second request. How do we do this in python? 
I am using python Flask framework.
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions
in this articles shows session like this.

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return 'Logged in as %s' % escape(session['username'])
    return 'You are not logged in'

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['username'] = request.form['username']
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return '''
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p><input type=text name=username>
            <p><input type=submit value=Login>
        </form>
    '''
```

I tried someting like this.

```
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, url_for, escape, request

session['username']= 'Tin Tin'
```

But I get runtime errors. Any hint?

Updated code,

```
@app.route('/session/')
def session():
    session['tmp'] = 'hey it is working'
   # print session['tmp']
   # session.pop('tmp', None)
  #  print session['tmp']
    return render_template('hello.html', name ='session')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = 'tsdhisiusdfdsfaSecsdfsdfrfghdetkey'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

After setting the key, I get the error

```
TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: That looks like it would work.

Comment: nOpe. it doesn't work.

Comment: could you add error traceback please?

Comment: try logging the value of request.form['username'] and check if its valid or not. And what error are u getting

Comment: don;t you have to set `app.secret_key` for session to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't name your routed method "session" - you're conflicting with [`flask.session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.session).

```
from flask import Flask, session, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/session/')
def set_session():
    session['tmp'] = 'hey it is working'
    return render_template('hello.html', name ='session')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = 'tsdhisiusdfdsfaSecsdfsdfrfghdetkey'
    app.run(debug=True)
```